# How to decode text in metadata?

Tags: android, metadata

I got a metadata.txt file from an android app and it contains some random text. But it's not random in fact. It contains some text which will be decoded when the app runs. Any idea in what format this text is and how to decode them into human readable text file? Following is a sample line from the above mentioned text file

IJCLa6UYAjMl10UCLDUjXm5+3UJWdZ0FFB/XQzlIFiV111u3CvnMtuXrkfO4LxnIDRkdGTx

Comment: How was it encoded? That should tell you exactly what you need to decode it

Comment: cricket_007, I have no idea. I'm hoping, from the sample text given, somebody can recognize it or give some clues

Comment: That's kinda like the point of encoding things... So they aren't human readable. Do you have access to the source code of the app you received this from?

Comment: Currently i don't have. Anyway, thanks for the replies.

Comment: It might be possible to tell, though. I'm just not too well versed in cryptography to know how